# Python Selenium send_keys() for non-input tag

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, selenium

## **The Problem**

I'm trying to change the page of a database (ReferenceUSA, requires paid or university credentials) using selenium by typing the page number in and clicking enter, but the catch is that the search box is in a div tag. send_keys() only works for input and textarea tags. Here's a picture of the [page navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bbYr.png), and here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="pager">
<div class="prev button" title="Hold down to scroll through records faster." style="float: left;">«</div>
<div class="page" style="text-align: center; margin: 0px 1em; float: left; width: 40px;">1</div>
<div class="next button" title="Hold down to scroll through records faster.">»</div><span style="clear: both;"></span></div>
```

## **My Attempt**

I figured out how to change the innerHTML, so I really only need to hit enter on the div tag. I thought of and tried changing the innerHTML for the next button (e.g. set current page to 1207 in next_button() function if I wanted to navigate to page 1208), but the functions are all written in a global file for the site, thousands of lines long, and they all feed off each other using the same 6 variables making it essentially unreadable. I've brought this problem to one of my CS professors to no avail.

There must be a simple solution, but I'm at a loss right now. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could offer some guidance

Comment: Screenshot and html will help.

Comment: Also how does hitting enter on the div tag help?

Comment: I don't think `sendKeys` works only on `input` and `textarea`, what error are you getting when you use `sendKeys` on `div`?

Comment: @TheChetan I added a screenshot and the relevant HTML. Hitting enter switches the page number to what you type when you're actually on the page, so I figure it should work in selenium as well.

Comment: @GaurangShah It doesn't return an error, but it doesn't do anything either. Maybe I'm not identifying the problem correctly? Here's the code I tried: `start_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "1207";', start_page)
start_page.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Comment: The enter is working for one of two reasons. (1) There is an onclick event that responds to the change. (2) there is a form submit

Comment: @TheChetan there is an onclick event, but it still doesn't work like I need it to. I'm trying to find an alternative method or a fix to my current one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Update:**

I ended up scrapping Selenium altogether and figured out how to do it using the Requests module. The following is the snippet of code for my workaround:

## Select start page

```
data_data = {
    'requestKey': page_data,  # Collected earlier in the code
    'direction': 'Ascending', # Collected with Chrome DevTools
    'pageIndex': page_index   # Page number - 1
}
data = r.post(SELECT_PAGE, data = data_data)
```

Rather than clicking the button in Selenium, I figured out every time the page number changed I was sending a POST request, so I just sent the POST request.